# Reference Request for a particular approach of (rigorous) statistical mechanics

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, probability-distributions, statistical-physics

I was reading [Mathematical Aspects of Quantum Field Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AKE1XN4) by. E. de Faria and W. de Melo, and the following caught my attention.

> In (Hamiltonian) mechanics, the states of a system are described by points in a phase space $\Gamma$. The observables - physical quantitites that are measurable in experiments - are described by real (or complex) valued functions on phase space. As it turns out, the observable form a $C^{*}$-algebra. As it became clear at the end of the nineteenth century, this description of a mechanical system is quite inadequate if the system has too many particles. In the new approach proposed by Gibbs and Boltzmann, one only talks about the probability that a system is in a given state. More precisely, in statistical mechanics the states are taken to be probability distributions on phase space $\Gamma$, whereas the observables become random variables on $\Gamma$ (not however that they still form an abelian $C^{*}$-algebra).

Most references I know on rigorous (classical) statistical mechanics deals with the first approach described by the authors. I always wanted to find a good mathematical reference in which the theory is addressed under this probability point of view: treating observables as random variables and states as probability distributions.

Are there good resources (books, papers) that provides a detailed exposition of classical statistical mechanics under this point of view?

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to distinguish equilibrium from non-equilibrium systems. For the former, a classic text is [Thermodynamic Formalism
The Mathematical Structure of Equilibrium Statistical Mechanics](https://www.google.nl/books/edition/Thermodynamic_Formalism/eODJauPWIK4C) by David Ruelle (2004).

I don't think there is a similarly rigorous and universally applicable mathematical framework for non-equilibrium systems.

Comment: I'd also include Ruelle's earlier book *Statistical Mechanics: Rigorous Results* (World Scientific, 1999), which treats classical and quantum (equilibrium) statistical mechanics in parallel.

Comment: If I may be allowed a "plug", you might also look at my book "Convexity in the Theory of Lattice Gases", Princeton U. Press (1979), and in particular the Introduction by Arthur Wightman.